# webpack 4 exports are not being exposed as configured

Tags: webpack-4

I am upgrading from Webpack 3 to 4.

All of my web pages effectively have 2 entry points: one that is shared across all pages and another one that is page specific.

I thought I had gotten everything to work with webpack 4, but it looked like some of my modules were executing twice; it turns out that each entry point bootstrapped a module, even if the module was in a shared js file.

The solution appeared to be to set `optimization.runtimeChunk = "single"`, which would tell webpack to share the runtime across all chunks.

Looking at the output of the js files, this looked work as expected; however, each of my entry points exposes its exports via the following configuration:

```
output: {... libraryTarget: "var", libarary: ["MyLibrary", "[name]"]}
```

When I load the webpage and try to access the exported objects/functions, I get an error, when I try the following:

```
MyLibrary["entry"]
```

where "entry" is the name of one of the entry points, the result is a number (instead of the expected object where the members are the various named exports).

If I remove the `optimization.runtimeChunk = "single"` setting, then `MyLibrary["entry"]` returns the expected object with my exports, but then I have the same problem of my modules potentially being boot strapped multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

When you specify `optimization.runtimeChunk = "single"`, it outputs a file called `runtime.js`. That file must be included in the web page in order for webpack to function. Once I included that file, everything started working as expected.

Pro tip:
`optimization.runtimeChunk = "single"` is a shortcut for:

```
optimization : {
  runtimeChunk: {
    name: 'runtime'
  }
}
```

If you rename "runtime" to be the same as another chunk, it will include the runtime code bits in that chunk.